# Osgi Spring DM - Retrieve all beans by Bundle

Tags: osgi, eclipse-virgo, spring-dm

Using Eclipse Virgo i have a Bundle with a bean that implements BundleContextAware, i add a addBundleListener and receive the events correctly when a Bundle is started or stoped, thats OK. and have a bundle installed by the bundleChanged event.

Now, i need retrieve all beans of application context of the bundle installed, whats is the best way to retrieve the application context of the bundle?

```
 public class PluginManager implements BundleContextAware {
               private BundleContext bundleContext;
          @Override
          public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
            this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
            bundleContext.addBundleListener(this);
           }

              @Override
         public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {


           Bundle bundle = event.getBundle();

    //HOW TO DO TO GET ALL BEANS OF BUNDLE

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with another Listener

```
  public class PluginManager implements BundleContextAware,OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener {
           private BundleContext bundleContext;
      @Override
      public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
        bundleContext.addBundleListener(this);
       }

          @Override
     public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {


       Bundle bundle = event.getBundle();

      //NOW use this method to receive destroy event

    }
    @Override
public void onOsgiApplicationEvent(OsgiBundleApplicationContextEvent event) {

             Bundle bundle = event.getBundle();

    PluginBundleDescriptor pluginBundleDescriptor = new PluginBundleDescriptor();
    pluginBundleDescriptor.setId(bundle.getBundleId());
    pluginBundleDescriptor.setName(bundle.getSymbolicName());
    pluginBundleDescriptor.setApplicationContext(event
            .getApplicationContext());
```

}
}

and publish the service with a interface OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener (this is important)

```
 <osgi:service id="bundleContextTrackerOSGi" ref="coreModuleManager"
interface="org.springframework.osgi.context.event.OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener" />
```